# Select a Specific Tracking Marker

Tags: workflow, interface, tracking

Is it possible to select a particular tracker by name?

For example, If I want to select `Track.009`, how can I do this without having to select each tracker individually and check if it's `Track.009`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Deselect all markers first (hit A)
2. Click on the track name in the `Dopesheet View` (i.e. `Track.009`), twice if it's initially selected (first click deselect, second click selects track as well as the track marker). The `Dopesheet View` of your Movie Clip is on the upper right in the default `Motion Tracking` screen.

[image: Blender Motion Tracking - Select Track Marker by Name]